# How to acess a table in Code-First-Database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

For my Project I want to access the database but I have no clue because it is my first time programming with ASP.net mvc.

I have already read through a bunch of guides but to no avail.

---

**Controller**
This right here is my controller which gets a Code from a Machine (e.g.: 123456) but when I want to access the database through this option I get the **No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.** Error Message.

```
namespace Qualitätskontrolle.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult StartPage(string Code)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Code);
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(.);

            var dbErgebnisse =  dbContext.Result.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < dbErgebnisse.Count; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(dbErgebnisse[i]);
            }
            return View();
        }
}
```

---

**Context Class**
I have read that the empty constructor should be removed but then I cannot access it in the Controller class.

```
namespace Qualitätskontrolle.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }


        public DbSet<Bilder> Bilder { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Prüfungen> Prüfungen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ergebnis> Result { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Typen> Typen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Typen_Pruefungen_Bilder> Typen_Pruefungen_Bilder { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Einstellungen_KoordinatenSys> Einstellungen_KoordinatenSys { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Einstellungen_KoordinatenSys>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.ID, c.BildID });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Ergebnis>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.BildID, c.TypenID, c.PruefungenID, c.BauTeilId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Typen_Pruefungen_Bilder>()
                 .HasKey(c => new { c.PruefungenID, c.TypenID });


        }
    }
}
```

---

**Model**
This is the model I need. I speficly need the **BauTeilId** for the Controller Class.

```
namespace Qualitätskontrolle.Models
{
    public class Ergebnis
    {

        [Key]
        public int TypenID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int PruefungenID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int BildID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [StringLength(254)]
        public string BauTeilId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        public string XLabel { get; set; }

        public int? X { get; set; }

        public string YLabel { get; set; }

        public int? Y { get; set; }

        public string FehlerCode { get; set; }

        public string FehlerName { get; set; }

        public string FehlerGruppe1 { get; set; }

        public string FehlerGruppe2 { get; set; }

        public int Result { get; set; }
        //1=IO 2=NIO

    }
```

The result should be a **list** of **BauTeilId** which I can then check with the **Code** from the Controller.

If you need further information I will reply quickly.

Comment: There is a mapping file in in the Visual Studio Project that is used to map the c# classes to the tables in the database.  The mapping is missing.

Comment: Do you know where it is located?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/cc716679(v=vs.100)

Comment: Follow this link [Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with a New database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio) step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assume that it's not asp.net mvc core.
You should create separate class which implement DbContext e.g

```
public class ApplicationCustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationCustomDbContext () : base("name=DefaultConnectionCustom")
    {
    }

    // DbSet for your Entities
}
```

and in web.config you should specific connection string e.g.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnectionCustom" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="___" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: It is asp.net mvc core

Comment: So in asp.net mvc core you should specify connection string in appsettings.json and in Startup.cs define in configuration: services.AddDbContext<ApplicationCustomDbContext >(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:DefaultConnectionCustom"]));

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues.

1. For `ApplicationDbContext` in .net core, you should register like below in `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection")));
   ```
2. For connectionstring, you could configure in `appsettings.json` like

   ```
   {
       "ConnectionStrings": {
           "ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=CoreMVC2_2;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
       }
   }
   ```
3. For use, you could resolve from constructure like

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {       
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;       
       public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
           _mapper = mapper;
           _context = context;
           _userManager = userManager;
           _userStore = userStore;
       }
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {

           var existingStudent = _context.Result.ToList();           
           return View();
       }        
   }
   ```